# Jooq insert statement without code generation

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jooq

I am using jOOQ to generate SQL statements. How can I create an insert statement? I am able to generate a select statement, but I am unable to generate an insert statement. I can create a select statement like this:

```
String selectSQL = create.select().from("author").getSQL();
```

How can I create the SQL statement for insert

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","abcd");
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(dbConnection,SQLDialect.MYSQL);
         String SQl = create.insertInto(Table<?> table("author"), Field<Object> field("id"),Field<Object> field("first_name").Field<Object> field("last_name")).values("1", "askdfj", "kdjvk").getSQL();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
create
    .insertInto(table("author"), field("id"), field("first_name"), field("last_name"))
    .values("1", "askdfj", "kdjvk")
```

Where `table` and `field` are a static import of `org.jooq.impl.DSL.table` and `org.jooq.impl.DSL.field`.

Note that your code had several syntax errors (eg `Table<?>` and `Field<Object>` where they don't belong, and a `.` instead of a `,`).

Answer (score -1):

On the official doc you have an [example](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.5/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/)

```
create.insertInto(AUTHOR,
    AUTHOR.ID, AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, AUTHOR.LAST_NAME)
  .values(100, "Hermann", "Hesse");
```

Comment: That is an example with code generation, but here the op is using the dynamic/untyped variant.